# disable compatibility checking in excel with python

Tags: python, excel

How can I modify this program not to check the excel file compatibility?

```
import glob
from win32com.client import Dispatch

for file in glob.glob('C:\Users\igyulavics\Desktop\GYI_python\proba_tervek\*.xlsx'):
    xl = Dispatch('Excel.Application')
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Add(file)
    wb.SaveAs(file[:-1], FileFormat=56)
    xl.Quit()
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: there is no error, but I have to click all the time yes on the popup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python / Excel : Turn off Office Excel Compatibility Checker Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41578066/python-excel-turn-off-office-excel-compatibility-checker-programmatically)

Comment: I tried, but it is still giving the pup up...